# How to construct an $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns so that there is only a unique solution and all are equal

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we are required to create $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns such that there is only 1 unique nontrivial solution and the solutions are equal to the others i.e. $x_1 = x_2 = \dots x_n$

What are the properties that such a system of equations need to have and how does one go about constructing it?

I think such a system exists because for $n=2$ and $n=3$, we can just draw lines in in a plane/space such that they intersect at one point only and the components of their coordinates are equal. However, I am not able to figure out what is it that makes such a system behave that way, and hence am not able to generalize to $n \times n$

Comment: $x_1=a$, $x_2=a$, ..., $x_n=a$.

Answer (score 1):

Take any invertible matrix $A$ and multiply that matrix with any vector $v$, so $b=Av$.  Then $Ax=b$ has the unique solution $v$.